# Cannot open Setting using expo with Linking.openURL('app-settings')

Tags: javascript, react-native, settings

Hello I tried to follow a tutorial on youtube on how to make the app open the location settings if the user has not enabled location services. However on his computer it is working ( he is using android emulator though) me with my Iphone XS (which I believe works on latest IOS version) does not do anything.

I've tried to open just setting or even a link on internet but it does not work

```
openSetting = () => {
    if(Platform.OS=='ios'){
      Linking.openURL('app-settings:')
    }
    else{
      IntentLauncherAndroid.startActivityAsync(
        IntentLauncherAndroid.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS
      );
    }
    this.setState({openSetting:false});

  }
```

```
<Button onPress={() => this.setState({isLocationModalVisible:false, openSetting:true})}
          title ="Enable Location Services"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

This is how it will work in Expo SDK 45.0:

```
Linking.openSettings()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to call the function that's it. I have checked your code it's working fine on both platform

```
<Button onPress={() => this.openSetting()} title ="Enable Location Services"/>
```

To call setState in same time

```
<Button onPress={() => {this.openSetting();
        this.setState({isLocationModalVisible:false, openSetting:true})}}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply however if I do what you said I won't be able to change state on click right? Can I do multiple stuff on a single onPress method?(it will be openSetting() but also state if the Modal and state of openSetting to true.

Comment: Hey, @ElPandario I updated my answer. Check it out.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your reply I have updated my question because there is something I don't understand even though I followed the react native documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Oh yeah working great now thanks a lot man! However I have an other problem right now, when I go to settings to switch location permission from never to always and I go back to the app it tells me "Experience needs permissions" and even though I say Allow the screen does not update with location information it keeps showing my error message which is "Permission to acces location was denied" 
 I have added Appstate I set appState: AppState.currentState (I basically followed the react native documentation for that)

```
appState: AppState.currentState
```

```
handleAppStateChange = nextAppState => {
    if(this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === 'active'){
      console.log('App has come to the foreground');
      this._getLocationAsync();
    }
    this.setState({appState : nextAppState});
  };
```

It looks like I get the location because if I refresh app it shows me the location coords but I have to refresh it. It does not change automatically. But now if I switch back location from always to never it will auto update to permission declined and show the modal back again.

Answer (score 0):

[According to the documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/linking/) currently you would call `Linking.openSettings()`